# Data mocking for UI tests

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angularjs-e2e, ui-testing

So we have a web app, and a bunch of E2E tests.

Its all great, except that its a major pain to keep the data in a valid state. We're trying to write the tests in a way that they should leave the data valid, but it is an overhead, and whenever the test fails it will affect a lot of other tests.

So

We've been trying to do a database restore after every test run (we run local dbs for testing) - its a pain

We've been looking at putting db on a virtual machine and making snapshots - licensing costs are high

I was experimenting with interceptors (it is an AngularJS app) that would intercept certain calls to services and return a predefined piece of data - its hard to get it to work properly and creates too much overhead

Its gotta be a very common pain point yet I can't seem to find much about ways to approach this. So how do you solve this?